# How to handle Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' (0x3aaf2fec) to 'NSDictionary' (0x3aaf33c0) error in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my application, I am getting JSON response from server and I using a common method for parsing the same for all API calls.

This is the JSON response.

```
{"event":"event_process","status":0,"data":""}
```

Here for this paritcular API the data parameter is coming as string, where as all other API returning a dictionary. So while parsing the same I am getting following error and app is crashing

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' (0x3aaf2fec) to 'NSDictionary' (0x3aaf33c0).

Is there any way to handle this error without crashing, so that app will run even if the data is string.

PS: I have tried the following solution but it did not work

```
var json: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]
do {
    json = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [String:AnyObject])!
} catch let error as NSError {
    // print(error)
}

// print(json)
var dict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
do {
    dict = try (json["data"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
} catch {
    dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
}
```

Comment: hey, in your sample data is empty string and obviously can't be casted to dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
(json["data"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

`data` is not a dictionary with strings as keys. It is an empty string: `"data":""`

If you want your application to stop crashing, stop trying to cast a string as a dictionary.

**Note:**

Further more, your app is crashing because you are force casting (using the exclamation mark after the `as`). Force casting and force unwrapping are generally bad ideas in 99% of cases. Use optional unwrapping (question mark instead of exclamation) and test for `nil` to avoid crashing your app when something goes wrong.

This is explained in depth in the free swift book from apple.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' to 'NSDictionary'

means that a `String` is expected but a `Dictionary` is passed.
The line which causes the error is

```
dict = try (json["data"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
```

The JSON reveals clearly that the value for key `data` is a `String`.

Your code doesn't compile anyway because `Dictionary` key subscripting does not `throw`.

This prevents the code from crashing using optional bindings.

```
do {
  if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject],
    jsonData = json["data"] as? String {
    print(jsonData)
    // do something with jsonData
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```